# Specific Unicode Symbols not appearing

Tags: unicode

Any suggestions why some Unicode symbols appear and not others? Specifically, I want to use the ue ligature (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d6b/index.htm), but this does not appear but other Unicode symbols such as em dash and capital gamma work fine. The ue ligature has a utf-8 encoding so I guess that means it isn’t a new Unicode addition. I have tried both using LuaLaTex and XeLaTex. Below is a snippet.

```
%em dash works
\symbol{"2014}
%capital gammas both work
\symbol{"0393} % hex
\symbol{915}   % dec
%ue ligature does not work
\symbol{"1D6B} % hex
\symbol{7531}   % dec
```

Thanks

Comment: If you are using a unicode tex, the symbol will appear or not appear depending if the symbol is in the font you are using. You have given no information about that. The log file will warn of missing symbols and tell you the font at that point.

Comment: There is no need to use `\symbol` here you could type the characters directly,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide an example but

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

%em dash works
\symbol{"2014}

%capital gammas both work
\symbol{"0393} % hex
\symbol{915}   % dec

%ue ligature does not work
\symbol{"1D6B} % hex
\symbol{7531}   % dec
\end{document}
```

Produces the warning

```
Missing character: There is no ᵫ (U+1D6B) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no ᵫ (U+1D6B) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!
```

As the Latin Modern Font doesn't have that character

Use a bigger font, say Noto Sans and you get no warning

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}

\begin{document}

%em dash works
\symbol{"2014}

%capital gammas both work
\symbol{"0393} % hex
\symbol{915}   % dec

%ue ligature does not work
\symbol{"1D6B} % hex
\symbol{7531}   % dec
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That worked although for some reason it couldn't find and install \setmainfont{Noto Sans} but need \setmainfont{NotoSans-Regular}.